# How to give docker exclusive access to cpus?

Tags: docker, lxc, cgroups, lxc-docker

Is there any way I can give a docker instance exclusive access to some of the cpus?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cpusets to specify where the docker containers can execute.
You can also specify cpu shares (cycles) to ensure, the docker container gets all the cycles available.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you mean `--cpuset-cpus=""`? This does not give the docker exclusive access. I'm looking for something more like `cpuset.cpu_exclusive`

Comment: Also add cpushares..although not exclusive, if you give max cycles, it will ensure your container gets pref over other processes seeking cycles for the cpu

Comment: As you mentioned, this is not exclusive!